# is it a bad idea to use voltages higher then 12v for electrolysis based hydrogen extraction?

Tags: electrolysis

I am currently using twelve volts from my power supply, it works fine but I do have the ability to put more then that, up to 2kv, I am using salt water - I know, this produces chlorine gas, I have that sorted.

If I was to, stupidly, put 240V or more either AC or DC, would it be advised to use a less conductive electrolyte? I am aware that this method requires a lot of power.

Comment: By increasing the voltage you would make an [electrode boiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrode_boiler) which produces some hydrogen as a side effect. For best results ditch the table salt (which eats up pretty much any common electrode you can think of) and use either sodium/potassium hydroxide or sulfuric acid as the electrolyte. Yes you will need to scrub the generated gases unless you want corrosive mist floating around.

Comment: If the generator is producing mixed hydrogen-oxygen, a corrosive electrolyte would demand an explosion-proof containment vessel. Bad enough with scalding hot brine.

Comment: I do not have any thing like that to hand, will baking soda do. I will be getting the correct stuff soon.

Comment: Does using AC have any advantages to using DC at the same volts amps?

Comment: AC will just heat the water, without producing much gas. As the electrodes constantly switch roles they essentially nullify the previous cycle every time.  Sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) is useless as an electrolyte. Sodium hydroxide (lye) and/or potassium hydroxide is commonly found as drain cleaner pellets at hardware stores. @SpheroPefhany is right, you *really* don't want that stuff on your skin, let alone eyes (blindness is a possible outcome). You absolutely want to keep the O2 and H2 separate, and bubble the gases trough a mild acid solution (e.g. vinegar) to scrub any caustic mist.

Answer (score 8):

Lower voltage at higher current is better.

Above the electrochemical voltage required  (~1.23VDC) I believe it's all waste (some of which you'll have to live with to get the current). You can increase the plate area or increase the conductivity of the solution.

Comment: I remember once seeing a Youtube of someone doing electrolysis with a high voltage, and claiming that the boiling of the water was clear proof that excess energy was being produced. Where else, he  asked, could all that energy be coming from?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Indeed - it's not like it's plugged into the mains or anything.